# Android / iOS input focused when tapping on page body

Tags: android, iphone, ios, webkit, mobile-safari

*The question is about the standard browser showing the HTML5 page, not the WebView*

The test device is Galaxy Tab 10.1, though this was also seen on iPad.

The page has a form. The form has fixed width and

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

When I touch and hold the page body (**outside of the form**), one of the form inputs (usually the 1st one, though sometimes the 2nd) is focused (and the on-screen keyboard is shown).

Any explanation why this behavior?
Any idea how to prevent it?

Comment: Do you have an example link to your problem page? May be easier to investigate the cause if i can see it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML5 autofocus](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_autofocus.asp) attribute to force the browser to initially focus on the element you want.

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" />
```

Older browsers will ignore the attribute.